# C++ error 'else' without a previous if

Tags: c++

I cant seem to see my error here. 
relatively new to C++.
 Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float salary,taxrate,incometax;

    cout << "Enter your Annual Salary" << endl;
    cin >> salary;

    if (salary>= 70000)
      taxrate = 0.4;
      incometax= taxrate*salary;
    else if
      taxrate= 0.3;
      incometax= taxrate*salary;

cout << "The income tax due is: R"<< incometax;
```

I am looking through my code and cannot find the error?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write Python code, where indentation is used for scoping. It's not like that in C++. I recommend you get a couple of [good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Answer (score 2):

The `else if` needs a condition to evaluate. So something like `else if(some condition){...}`.

If you're looking to default after the first `if` fails, just use `else{...}`.

Also, you need curly braces around your if and else blocks, and at the end of main.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float salary,taxrate,incometax;

    cout << "Enter your Annual Salary" << endl;
    cin >> salary;

    if (salary>= 70000){
      taxrate = 0.4;
      incometax= taxrate*salary;
    }
    else{
      taxrate= 0.3;
      incometax= taxrate*salary;
    }

    cout << "The income tax due is: R"<< incometax;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I just simplified my code by concatenating the incometax... statement with the else and it works

Comment: Glad it worked! Consider accepting the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some syntax and logical errors. Like `else if()` have to given condition, income will be **modified twice**  if you will not put parenthesis.
I will suggest you to follow some tutorial for learning syntax of language.

modified code is below with changes described as comments  .

```
#include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        float salary,taxrate,incometax;

        cout << "Enter your Annual Salary" << endl;
        cin >> salary;

        if (salary>= 70000)//without braces {} if includes only one statement in it
          taxrate = 0.4;
        else         //else if() have to given a condition so use else instead
          taxrate= 0.3;

          incometax= taxrate*salary;//it is conman for both so no need to put it 2 times  

    cout << "The income tax due is: R"<< incometax;
```

Comment: Thanks I am writing a new program. same error. I applied your advice and its working fine. i now know to remember the { }

Comment: so you can accept the answer so others can get help